# How to troubleshoot [ERROR] Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!') in pyodbc

Tags: aws-lambda, extract, pyodbc, unixodbc, datadirect

I'm working on extracting data from an external cloud-based source via a DataDirect Hybrid Data Pipeline ODBC Driver. The actual extraction is run through an AWS Lambda function that is invoked via step functions. **Full disclosure - I'm punching a bit above my weight here in terms of expertise. I'm a data analyst by title and a software engineer by hobby.
**

We're using Python for the connection and Docker to develop the extraction script in a runtime environment that mimics the Lambda runtime environment. I'm getting the following error in the `pyodbc.connect()` line before any other queries or connections are made:

```
[ERROR] Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

Searches online show that this could be any number of issues, but the error isn't descriptive enough for me to figure out what to do next.

What troubleshooting steps can I take to either work to solve this, or try to get a more descriptive error to point me in the right direction?

TIA

**​ Notes that may be helpful:**

- unixODBC is installed
- pyodbc successfully imports
- The 64-bit DataDirect ODBC driver is installed in the environment
- The pyodbc connection string I'm using in the Linux environment works when the process is done on a windows machine (with the windows driver)

The troubleshoot steps I've taken so far was testing the connection using a windows EC2 instance. The data successfully pulled using the exact same connection string I'm passing to pyodbc in the linux environment.